# adding multiple colours to density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add 92 different colours to my lines and legend. How is this done?

```
plotDensities(d.Tissue.spike,main = "", legend=F)
legend("topright", legend = legendCRC_Tissue, ncol = 2, cex=0.25)
```

I tried something like this:

```
 col <- cm.colors(92, alpha = 1)
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some example data?

Comment: Please don't. Wanting to use **92** different colors on your plot is a clear indication that you need think more deeply about **how** you represent your data. Your current idea seems problematic.